# Extract a specific gene from several prokka-annotated sequences

Tags: annotations, extract

I annotated 500 sequences with Prokka from which I need to specifically extract only TcdA gene from all sequences, I need use the annotation of .ffn file of all sequences.

¿How can I do this automatically without having to open each folder of each sequence noted?

**Prokka files:**

> Strain1

```
  >Strain1.err
  >Strain1.faa
  >Strain1.fna
  >Strain1.ffn *I use this file for extract gene*
```

*I need the TcdA gene of the 500 sequences*

> Strain1_01428 glycosylating toxin TcdA
> ATGTCTTTAATATCTAAAGAAGAGTTAATAAAACTCGCATATAGCATTAGACCAAGAGAA
> AATGAGTATAAAACTATATTAACTAATTTAGACGAATATAATAAGTTAACTACAAACAAT
> AATGAAAATAAATATTTACAATTAAAAAAACTAAATGAATCAATTGATGTTTTTATGAAT
> AAATATAAAAATTCAAGCAGAAATAGAGCACTCTCTAATCTAAAAAAAGATATATTAAAA
> GAAGTAATTCTTATTAAAAATTCCAATACAAGTCCTGTAGAAAAAAATTTACATTTTGTA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like:

```
for i in /path/to/*.ffn; do awk 'BEGIN {RS=">"} /glycosylating toxin TcdA/ {print ">"$0}' $i > TcdA.fasta; done
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: *It worked for me, only with a few modification '' and run in the same folder of my .ffn files: 

   ` for i in '*.ffn' ; do awk 'BEGIN {RS=">"} /glycosylating toxin TcdB/ {print ">"$0}' $i > TcdB.fasta; done`

Thanks a lot !!